# How to add custom uploaded images to cart in magento 1.4.1.1?

Tags: magento

How to add custom fields as well as custom images to cart in magento 1.4.1.1 ?

Any one have any idea about this???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need add you custom product attribute to shopping cart, just add the following lines of code into your module configuration:

```
<config>
     <global>
          <sales>
               <quote>
                    <item>
                        <product_attributes>
                             <[your_custom_attribute_code] />
                        </product_attributes>
                    </item>
               </quote>
          </sales>
     </global>
</config>
```

Just replace **[your_custom_attribute_code]** with the code of your attribute. 
You may also add as many attributes as you wish, just add one more attribute into configuration.

Comment: Thank you for something new that I didn't know before.

Comment: but [your_custom_attribute_code]  this code is dynamic for different attributes so it is not possible for client to follow this XML format structure.

Comment: I suppose it is for developers and not for clients. By the way, the other way is to override quote_items collection, it is not possible for clients either :) Anyway, you can always write a cusotmization, that will add these attributes via Magento Admin interface to configuration of Magento. You just need to call method `Mage::getConfig()->setNode('node/path', 'nodeValue');`.