# Multiple Origin Zip Codes in Magento Checkout

Tags: magento, zipcode, ups

I'm working on a Magento storefront for a client.  They use dropshippers, so a single zip code doesn't do us much help.  We do have it set for the most common zip code from which the client ships, so, in many cases, it's ok.

However, in some cases, there is a different origin zip code that needs to be used.  In more rare cases, we will have multiple origin zip codes.  When there is a zip that differs from the main one, we have stored this in an attribute called 'origin zip' (creative, huh?)

Where should I be looking to make the modifications?  We're only using the UPS shipping method, and what I'm looking to do is, before calculating shipping, to grab whatever origin zips may be in the cart (I think we've got this part), but then, depending on the results, I may need to iterate through the shipping calculation and add the values together - i.e. in the case they order one product with an origin zip code, and another product without an origin zip code, it would have to calculate the first, then the second, and then add them together.

If someone could point us in the correct direction of which php files or classes we'll need to modify, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to add your custom attributed to list of attributes that will be used in shopping cart. 
Follow these answer on stackoverflow:
[How to add custom uploaded images to cart in magento 1.4.1.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4021328/how-to-add-custom-uploded-images-to-cart-in-magento-1-4-1-1/4037256#4037256)

Then you need to create your custom shipping method, maybe extended from yours one. It should walk through items it receives from shipping request and check for different zip origin, then calculate rate for them separately.

I hope for you it will not be a problem to create a module that will extend existing shipping method functionality.

Cheers!

**UPDATE**
For adding your attribute to product that is loaded in the cart item use such configuration:

```
<config>
     <global>
          <sales>
               <quote>
                    <item>
                        <product_attributes>
                             <origin_zip />
                        </product_attributes>
                    </item>
               </quote>
          </sales>
     </global>
</config>
```

Then in shipping method model use something like this (used USPS as example):

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
{
    if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
        return false;
    }

    $defaultOriginZip = Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/postcode', $this->getStore());

    $requestDataByOriginZip = array();
    // Walking through quote items
    foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $quoteItem) {
        // If virtual or not shippable separately, it should be skipped
        if ($quoteItem->isVirtual() || $quoteItem->isDummy(true)) {
            continue;
        }
        // Retrieving origin zip code
        if ($quoteItem->getProduct()->getOriginZip()) {
            $zipCodeForCalculation = $quoteItem->getProduct()->getOriginZip();
        } else {
            $zipCodeForCalculation = $defaultOriginZip;
        }

        if (!isset($requestDataByOriginZip[$zipCodeForCalculation])) {
            // Default values initialization for this zip code
            $requestDataByOriginZip[$zipCodeForCalculation] = array(
                'orig_postcode' => $zipCodeForCalculation,
                'package_weight' => 0,
                'package_value' => 0,
                // etc...
            );
        }

        $requestDataByOriginZip[$zipCodeForCalculation]['package_weight'] += $quoteItem->getRowWeight();
        $requestDataByOriginZip[$zipCodeForCalculation]['package_value'] += $quoteItem->getBaseRowTotal();
        // Etc...
    }

    $results = array();
    foreach ($requestDataByOriginZip as $requestData) {
       $requestByZip = clone $request; // Cloning to prevent changing logic in other shipment methods.
       $requestByZip->addData($requestData);
       $this->setRequest($requestByZip);
       // Returns rate result for current request
       $results[] = $this->_getQuotes();
    }

    $yourMergedResult = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');

    foreach ($results as $result) {
       // Logic for merging the rate prices....
    }

    return $yourMergedResult;
}
```

Comment: Hi Ivan - I get what your saying to add it - my attribute is origin_zip.  Would I just use that identifier and then it would be available in the cart?  How would I get it for the item?  So, where should I start to iterate through the cart and get that attribute for a given product?  Thanks!

Comment: Hi Ivan - thanks for the examples - your the man.  For anyone else wondering (because I was confused about this) the config doesn't go into the shipping module config.xml, but rather the Checkout config.xml folder.  I was putting it in with the shipping module wondering why I couldn't get it, but when I placed it in checkout, it populated right away.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The class `usa/shipping_ups` is what handles these requests, and specifically the method `setRequest` seems to have what you need:

```
    if ($request->getOrigPostcode()) {
        $r->setOrigPostal($request->getOrigPostcode());
    } else {
        $r->setOrigPostal(Mage::getStoreConfig('shipping/origin/postcode', $this->getStore()));
    }
```

If you can add the orig_postcode to the shipping request, UPS will return a quote based on that origin.

One approach to this would be to override `Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request` and add a method called `getOrigPostcode`. By virtue of being a real method, this would override the default Magento getter/setter behavior. Have this method query the contents of the request to find out which zip needs to be used.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Hi Joe - good call.  What we've done is copied over the UPS module into our own custom shipping module and now we're working on reworking the zip code portion to fit this purpose.  I'll post a comment here once we get it working to let you (and anyone else interested) know if we were able to manipulate that call to get it working.  Thanks!